# Magento Multistore setup in the subfolder

Tags: magento

I want to run the magento multistore in the subfolder with the different theme.

Suppose I have a main store with the custom theme and I have configured the second store B in a sub folder and put the `index.php` and the `.htaccess` file and made the required changes into it, and now the home page of the second store is coming.

Here is my question: How can I get all the categories listing in the left sidebar and how will I be able to implement my custom theme for the second store, like product listing page, product description page and the cart page?

Is it done by the files of the my main store or do I have to upload all the files into the second store B and from here I can edit all the things?

Comment: Take a look @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13315580/magento-multistore-subfolder-without-symlinks

Answer (score 0):

in your sub folder you can create symlinks to app, includes, js, skin and var directories of the base installation. So your second store will be able to access all files from base store and you can perform all changes in one app/design, skin folder

Answer (score 0):

Create your theme in your style.

you can change your theme in your second template .

go to system->configuration.

select your store in Current Configuration Scope:.

in General->design.load in main magento installed folder.

second store only have .htaccess and indes.php

all files You up

[image: Theme applay to second store (multi store)]