# magento multistore subfolder without symlinks

Tags: magento

It's possible to setup a magento multistore with subfolders/subdirectories without need of create symlinks?

```
For example:
www.mainstore
www.mainstore/store1
www.mainstore/store2
www.mainstore/store3
```

Some hosting providers have disabled the symlinks for security reasons, and the normal method is making one folder for each store in the magento root foolder, copy in them index.php and .htaccess and make symlinks to all the other magento folders, like this:

```
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/app/ app
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/includes/ includes
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/js/ js
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/lib/ lib
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/media/ media
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/skin/ skin
ln -s /home/example/example.com/html/var/ var
```

I think that maybe is possible with .htaccess rewritings, but I don't know how I can setup this.

thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look @ [Magento Multi store setup sub folders](http://www.dbits.be/blog/index.php/How-To/magento-multi-store-setup-sub-folders.html)

To setup multi store using the same folder using  .htaccess.

After setting up your stores in magento update your .htaccess file

```
SetEnvIf Host www\.store1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host www\.store1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website
SetEnvIf Host ^store1\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=base
SetEnvIf Host ^store1\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website

SetEnvIf Host www\.store2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store2
SetEnvIf Host www\.store2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
SetEnvIf Host ^store2\.com MAGE_RUN_CODE=store2
SetEnvIf Host ^store2\.com MAGE_RUN_TYPE=store
```

Read more @

- [Multi-Site, Multi-Domain Setup](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup)
- [Setting Up MAGENTO with Multiple Websites or store](http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/setting-up-magento-with-multiple-websites-or-stores)

Comment: Thanks @R.S. I am referring to one magento installation in a unique domain with differents subfolders, not with differents domains. For example: http://domain.com/store1 http://domain.com/store2 Can you help me with this? thanks!

Comment: I was trying your example in a magento root, but appears all time 404 error. If I make a folder with the magento store2 name like /magento_root/store2 and copy inside an index.html and default .htaccess don't show the 404 error and loads, but don't have all the needed files for show the sotore because isn't the symlinks.I was tried to insert inside the /store2 folder in the htaccess but still without work. You know how I can insert a rewrites in the .htaccess that make the same function that the symlinks? thanks! :)

Comment: Take a look @ http://www.dbits.be/blog/index.php/How-To/magento-multi-store-setup-sub-folders.html

Comment: I can confirm that this solution works perfect! thanks for that :)